# $m^2$ term in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, field-theory

Consider the following Hamiltonian :
$$ \mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( \partial_{0} \phi \right )^2 + \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 +\frac{1}{2} \left ( \nabla \phi \right )^2
$$
Recently I faced some difficulty with this Hamiltonian. If we try to use the discretized version of this lagrangian we consider a lattice whit N-Sites where on each site we put a particle then the Hamiltonian will contain the kinetic term + each site potential term and the coupling term between NN sites, the point is, in that case, the Hamiltonian would be:
$$ \mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2m} \left ( \partial_{0} \phi \right )^2 + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 \phi^2 +\frac{1}{2} m\Omega^2 \left ( \nabla \phi \right )^2
$$
where $\Omega$ is the strength of coupling. My question is two fold

1. how these two terms are related? I mean how can I start from the second one and find the first one?
2. In the second Hamiltonian, how can I relate $\Omega$ to $ \omega$?

Comment: What metric are you using? As is, it looks like the connections between neighbors should cancel, leaving you with an infinite collection of uncoupled simple harmonic oscillators. This is because I interpret $(\partial_\mu\phi)^2 = \dot\phi^2 - (\nabla\phi)^2$ in a $(+,-,-,-)$ metric.

Comment: Common metric on Special relativity(exactly what you've mentioned), And no, I'm quite sure the coupling term is still there because the gradient term still exists. @SeanE.Lake

Comment: I fixed the question there were some subtle mistakes. @SeanE.Lake

Comment: Now it's even more confusing to me. As I understand the conventions in relativity and Einstein summation, $(\partial_i\phi)^2 = (\nabla\phi)^2$, meaning there isn't even a kinetic term. Should that, maybe, be $(\nabla_\mu\phi)^2$ (i.e. the covariant derivative)? Or maybe $(\partial_0\phi)^2$ instead of $\partial_i$ and this is the Hamiltonian density (the signs on your potential terms make more sense, then)?

Comment: @SeanE.Lake I am so sorry, yes you are right, I fixed the issue and yes this is hamiltonian density, my mistake I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the free Klein-Gordon Hamiltonian. Strictly, you should be writing this in terms of the momentum canonically conjugate to $\phi$. By convention, we use the symbol $\pi$ for that. So, your original Hamiltonian density is
\begin{array}
    \mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2} \pi^2 + \frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2.
\end{array}
There's a good reason for being a stickler about notation in this way. You'll see, presently.

First, make the substitution $m\rightarrow \omega$ to get
\begin{array}
    \mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2} \pi^2 + \frac{\omega^2}{2}\phi^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2.
\end{array}
Next, make the change of field coordinate $\phi\rightarrow \sqrt{m}\phi$. The reason for being such a stickler about notation is that, if you work it out carefully (for instance, by doing the change of variables using the action/Lagrangian density and then transitioning back to the Hamiltonian picture) you'll find that rescaling $\phi$ in this way also requires you to make the substitution $\pi\rightarrow \pi/\sqrt{m}$. That gives you
\begin{array}
   \mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2m} \pi^2 + \frac{m\omega^2}{2}\phi^2 + \frac{m}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2.
\end{array}

The addition of $\Omega$ is just something that is done by hand, afterward. It is totally unrelated to $\omega$.

What you will find, though, is that the lattice supports modes that have frequencies that look like $$\omega_{\mathrm{mode}} = \sqrt{\omega^2 + \Omega^2 \mathbf{k}^2},$$
with $k$ some version of the wave number appropriate to your lattice.

Comment: Based on your description the strength of the gradient term only depends on mass, which is not true if we use the discretized version because in that case the strength of coupling between NN- neighbors does not only demand on mass. So how can I deal with that problem?

Comment: @Jason As I said, you add the $\Omega^2$ by hand ad hoc.

Comment: So What your saying is that basically the $\Omega$ does not depend on $\omega$ or $m$ whatsoever?

Comment: @Jason That's right. It's a parameter added specifically to control the strength of the interaction between neighboring points on the lattice. I confess, I'm not an expert on lattice theory, so I can't tell you why it's done that way.

Comment: could you give me a hint on how to derive that relation for $\omega_{mode}$ that you've written?

Comment: @Jason Do another change of coordinates: $$\phi(\mathbf{x},t) = \int \tilde{\phi}(\mathbf{k},t) \frac{e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \,\mathrm{d}^3k.$$ Note that $\pi$ probably won't transform in the same way.